# Implementing an openstreetmaps marker event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, openlayers, openstreetmap, marker

Have a loop to show markers with events on Openstreemaps for example:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= length; i++) {

    instance.markers[provider][index]['marker'] = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    instance.map_instance[divBlock].map.addLayer(instance.markers[provider][index]['marker']);
    instance.markers[provider][index]['icon'] = new OpenLayers.Icon(coord_data.img_icon, new OpenLayers.Size(17,17));
    var mark = new OpenLayers.Marker(center, instance.markers[provider][index]['icon']);
    mark.events.register('click', mark, function(evt){
        alert(coord_data.file);
    });
    instance.markers[provider][index]['marker'].addMarker(mark);
}
```

Events in this code is not working.

Next event.register works but on whole markers inside layer:

```
instance.map_instance[divBlock].map.events.register('click', instance.markers[provider][index]['marker'], function(evt){
    alert(coord_data.file);
});
```

How can I add event personally to each marker in this loop?

Answer (score 0):

for that you have to bind your data **coord_data.file** with each Marker Object.

for that you can use any **marker Attribute** Like.. id,title...

**Example:**

```
var mark = new OpenLayers.Marker(center, instance.markers[provider][index]['icon']);
mark.title = coord_data.file;
mark.events.register('click', mark, function(evt){
    alert(this.title);
});
```

hope this'll work.